# how to create graph using php where data source is navicat(mysql)

Tags: php, navicat

I have 2 tableS in Navicat.

Database name : SQA

Table1

```
+-----------+--------------+----------+-----------+  
| date      | TRAFFIC      | PAYLOAD1 | PAYLOAD11 | 
+-----------+--------------+----------+-----------+ 
|2015-01-01 | 200          | 278      | 221       |
|2015-01-01 | 300          | 389      | 245       |
|2015-01-02 | 250          | 276      | 345       |
|2015-01-02 | 350          | 399      | 212       |
+-----------+--------------+----------+-----------+
```

table2

```
+--------------------------------------+------------+  
| date      | TRAFFIC2     | PAYLOAD21 | PAYLOAD121 | 
+-----------+--------------+-----------+------------+ 
|2015-01-01 | 440          | 344       | 551        |
|2015-01-01 | 500          | 980       | 315        |
|2015-01-02 | 120          | 276       | 422        |
|2015-01-02 | 90           | 399       | 212        |
+-----------+--------------+-----------+-----+------+
```

I want to create 2 charts from Navicat using PHP, but before it, I must sum `PAYLOAD` and `TRAFFIC` ordered by date.

```
Chart1 = date in X axis and traffic in Y axis

Chart2 = date in X axis and payload in Y axis
```

Please help me.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! What have you already researched and tried out yourself? It would greatly motivate the SO community into helping you if you would not simply ask "*How should I do this?*", but also show significant effort from your side into solving your own problem.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is just a server-side scripting language. It only returns raw data to the client, typically. It has image-creation capabilities, but these are largely inefficient for graphing as they use server-side resources rather than have the client use its own power.

I'd suggest delivering the data in the form of some object notation, like [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) or [XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML), and then having JavaScript render a graph. One library for JavaScript graph implementation is [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/).